# I need to join 2 Tables based on the NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-null

My Tables are able follows

Table name: **Student**

| NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| Jason | X |
| John | **NULL** |

Table name: **Status**

| STATUS | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| X | Active |
| NULL | Inactive |

I cannot get the expected results when I join the 2 tables since NULL is not equal to NULL in MySQL.

I tried with the below code

```
Select a.NAME , b.DESCRIPTION
from STUDENT a
LEFT JOIN STATUS b ON a.STATUS = b.STATUS;
```

The result I am getting is are below

| NAME | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| Jason | Active |
| John | **NULL** |

**Expected Result**

| NAME | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| Jason | Active |
| John | Inactive |

Comment: There is no question here. PS Also no specification of how the result is a function of the inputs. Don't expect us to guess from 1 example & wrong code.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either  with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually one NULL is not equal to another NULL.

You need in NULL-safe compare operator `<=>`:

```
SELECT a.name, b.description 
FROM student a 
LEFT JOIN status b ON a.status <=> b.status;
```

Comment: Hi @Akina is it safe to use this operator? 
Are there any disadvantages to using this?

Comment: @JasonJoelPinto Where would the problems come from.. the most common operator.